What does the icon with the two diagonal red lines that appeared on my uploaded videos mean?
What does this red double diagonal line logos/icons mean on videos I uploaded to YouTube?

I uploaded these videos using the app. There is no help at all on YouTube about this, and I can't figure out what the marks mean.

 
That is a version of the YouTube Shorts logo.
It is now typically seen with the play button overlaid.  I expect the videos you uploaded were shot on a mobile device and oriented vertically, as opposed to widescreen, and less than 60 seconds long.
Additional Resource: Wikipedia > YouTube Shorts
